How can I exclude a specific UI element from the Material 3 Compose library?
Let's say I have followed the directions here to add the material 3 compose dependencies.
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3#kts
dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-adaptive-navigation-suite:1.0.0-alpha05")
}

android {
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.1.1"
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

I do not want anybody on my team to use the Button class in material 3 because I have already created a custom button that is preferred. I don't even want them to have access to the material 3 button class. I would also settle for some sort of way of marking this Button with a "do not use" flag so people know not to use it. How can I do this?

You should be able to write a Lint rule, or a detekt rule, or the equivalent that complains about the use of the wrong Button() function.

Thanks for the comment. I see RestrictedApi(https://googlesamples.github.io/android-custom-lint-rules/checks/RestrictedApi.md.html). However, I don't see of any way to add this to 3rd party functions.

Agreed, so you will not be able to leverage some existing Lint/detekt/whatever rule, unless you can find one that is configurable. Somebody eventually will write something for that, as it is a clear need: rules to enforce use of a design system. I do not know if one exists right now, though.
